# How do you test an application integrated with a payment system?

Tags: testing, payment-gateway

Suppose I have a website that receives money through a payment gateway when people register to the site.

How do you test it? Can it be done without real money?

Comment: Paypal: https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_Sandbox_UserGuide/overview.html - Authorize.net: https://developer.authorize.net/testaccount/ - Google http://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?answer=134469 -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most payment gateways, e.g. Paypal, provide sandbox instances and fake credit card numbers that you can use for testing.